Minimum number of elements in all sets
I have an interesting problem:
Several (K) people go to the bookstore to buy books. Each person buys four (different) (more generally, m) books, and every two people share exactly (only) two (more generally, n, where 1 ≤ n ≤ m) of the same books. Now, what is the minimum number of kinds of books that can meet these conditions?
For 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 people with two shared books, we can use a construction method to create the sets as follows:
#### Case with 2 People

    A =   {1, 2, 3, 4}    
    B =   {1, 2, 5, 6}    

#### Case with 3 People

    A =   {1, 2, 3, 4}    
    B =   {1, 2, 5, 6}    
    C =   {3, 4, 5, 6}    

#### Case with 4 People

    A =   {1, 2, 3, 4}    
    B =   {1, 2, 5, 6}    
    C =   {1, 3, 5, 7}    
    D =   {1, 4, 6, 7}    

#### Case with 5 People

    A =   {1, 2, 3, 4}    
    B =   {1, 2, 5, 6}    
    C =   {1, 3, 5, 7}    
    D =   {1, 4, 6, 7}    
    E =   {2, 3, 6, 7}    

#### Case with 6 People

    A =   {1, 2, 3, 4}    
    B =   {1, 2, 5, 6}    
    C =   {1, 3, 5, 7}    
    D =   {1, 4, 6, 7}    
    E =   {2, 3, 6, 7}    
    F =   {2, 4, 5, 7}    

#### Case with 7 People

    A =   {1, 2, 3, 4}    
    B =   {1, 2, 5, 6}    
    C =   {1, 3, 5, 7}    
    D =   {1, 4, 6, 7}    
    E =   {2, 3, 6, 7}    
    F =   {2, 4, 5, 7}    
    G =   {3, 4, 5, 6}    

So, for 2 and 3 people, we need 6 kinds of books; for 4, 5, 6, and 7 people, we need 7 kinds of books.
For K >= 8 people, it seems that constructing the sets becomes much more challenging.
One possible solution is:
Fix the shared two kinds of books the same between every two people, then the remaining two books of every person must be different. So the final result is:
2 + K * 2 = 2K + 2     ......(1)

This is indeed the general right construction, and I suspect this is indeed the minimum construction (if K > 7). However, I cannot find any mathematical proof to confirm this or deny this.
So, does anyone have the right answer?
For a more general problem:
K people go to the bookstore to buy books. Each person buys M different books, and every two people share exactly N (where 1 ≤ N ≤ M) of the same books. Now, what is the minimum number of kinds of books that can meet these conditions?
A general construction is like the following:
N + (M - N) * K       ......(2)


So, is it possible to get an algorithm to construct and verify the problem, and then find the minimum construction?
Is there an general method/formula to get the miminum number?
formula (1) & (2) are the miminum or not? How about the right answer?

Please kindly help me!

This earlier question is about the special case where $n=1$. I answered that question, but could only give partial results.

@Mike Thanks so much for your kindly reply.This question should be an more general and the inverse problem of yours.Your answer is very inspiring.

I'm not sure I'm understanding but 2k+2 is not the construction method given above e.g. K=4 the construction method uses only 7 books but 2(4)+2 = 10

yes! 2K+2 is the construction result, but not the mininum (especiall for small K).I suspect that for very big K, 2K+2 is the miminum,but I can not proof.
